# Can not read property 'prototype' of undefined when i try to run angular project

Tags: angular

Everything is run good,but when I install project in another PC and then go for run that project and, I get below error.This project is working fine in my current PC but error is generated when put it on another PC.

I do the npm install and also check for version related changes but nothing happens. 
                                           ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/public/app/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35:42)
  at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/public/app/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:16:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)

This is my enviroment:

   Node : v8.11.3

This is my package.json:

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }

I think it is angular version related problem but i can't get any solution.
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: I already tried it but same error generated.@AmitChigadani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u getting this error ?? while running

> npm update

than you must try to delete node modules from your project or root directory and than again run

> npm install

Comment: Try to update your **karma** version in dev dependencies in package.json